# RGB colours from a .csv file R

Tags: r, csv, plot, rgb

I am concerned with the follwing issue: I have a .csv file with the RGB colours of my companies corporate design.

```
cols <-   read.table("cols.csv")
```

as you don't have the file, some info

```
str(cols)
```

returns

'data.frame':   66 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 66 levels "0,0,0","0,122,155",..: 1 64 5 20 37 56 57 58 59 60 ...
and

```
cols
```

returns

```
           V1
1        0,0,0

2      51,51,51

3   102,102,102
```

.
.
.

My idea is to plot a vektor, and using of the 66 rgb colour codes from my file using the rgb command in R.
However, if i do this:

```
x<-seq(0,2,0.2)

barplot(x, col=rgb(cols$V1[1],maxColorValue=255))
```

I get

```
Error in rgb(cols$V1[1], maxColorValue = 255) : 
  argument "green" is missing, with no default
```

I hope I have been able to make myself clear.

Kind regards and thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that your problem is coming from your very first step. If your file is a `csv` file, then use `read.csv`. You will now have **three** columns. You can refer to them using

```
 cols$V1, cols$V2, cols$V3
```

To use the `rgb` function, just have

```
rgb(cols$V1[1], cols$V2[1], cols$V3[1])
```